# Disable a group of tests in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a test spec which `describes` a class and within that has various `contexts` each with various `it` blocks.

Is there a way I can disable a `context` temporarily?

I tried adding a `pending "temporarily disabled"` call at the very top within a `context` I want to disable, and I did see something about pending when I ran the spec but then it just continued to run the rest of the tests.

This is what I kind of had:

```
describe Something
  context "some tests" do
    it "should blah" do
      true
    end
  end

  context "some other tests" do
    pending "temporarily disabled"

    it "should do something destructive" do
      blah
    end
  end
end
```

but like I said it just went on to run the tests underneath the pending call.

Searching led me to this [mailing list thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/rspec-users@rubyforge.org/msg15297.html) in which the the creator (?) of rspec says it's possible in rspec 2, which I'm running. I guess it did work but it didn't have the desired effect of disabling all of the following tests, which is what I think of when I see a `pending` call.

Is there an alternative or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

To disable a tree of specs using **RSpec 3** you can:

```
before { skip }
# or 
xdescribe
# or 
xcontext
```

You can add a message with *skip* that will show up in the output:

```
before { skip("Awaiting a fix in the gem") }
```

with **RSpec 2**:

```
before { pending }
```

Comment: How do you exactly do that on a block that has:
```describe 'XXXXX' do
....
end```

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos Just add it to the line following `describe 'XXXXX' do`. Worked like a charm, thanks @Pyro!

Comment: I can't get this to work with rspec 3 for some reason.

Comment: with rspec 3 `pending` assures that specs are failed, but you can use `skip` or even just `xdescribe` http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new_example_group_aliases____

Comment: This is nice.  You can also include a message after 'skip' that will show up in the output.

Comment: @JanHettich How do I do this with xdescribe?

Comment: This option is a lot better than pending, as pending runs the test and expects them to fail.

Answer (score 48):

Use [exclusion filters](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/filtering/exclusion-filters).
From that page:
In your `spec_helper.rb` (or `rails_helper.rb`)

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.filter_run_excluding :broken => true
end
```

In your test:

```
describe "group 1", :broken => true do
  it "group 1 example 1" do
  end

  it "group 1 example 2" do
  end
end

describe "group 2" do
  it "group 2 example 1" do
  end
end
```

When I run "rspec ./spec/sample_spec.rb --format doc"

Then the output should contain "group 2 example 1"

And the output should not contain "group 1 example 1"

And the output should not contain "group 1 example 2"

Answer (score 22):

See what you think of this:

```
describe "something sweet", pending: "Refactor the wazjub for easier frobbing" do
  it "does something well"
  it "rejects invalid input"
end
```

I like to see reasons with my pending items when I'm disabling something for "a while". They serve as little comments/TODOs that are presented regularly rather than buried in a comment or an excluded example/file.

Changing `it` to `pending` or `xit` is quick and easy, but I prefer the hash construction. It gives you every-run documentation, is a drop-in (doesn't change describe/context/it so I have to decide what to use again later), and is just as easily removed if the decision is made or blocker is removed.

This works the same for groups and individual examples.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it works the same for describe but in thest pending actually runs the test, and fails if the test begins to pass. The xdescribe (I guess just like xit) - just doesn't run it.

Comment: confirmed that this works, with both `pending:` and `skip:`, in rspec 3.6.0. Seems like the best solution to me. in rspec3 pending still runs tests, but `skip` does not (however you apply the `skip`).

Answer (score 9):

another one. https://gist.github.com/1300152

use xdescribe, xcontext, xit to disable it.

Update:

Since rspec 2.11, it includes xit by default. so the new code will be

```
# put into spec_helper.rb
module RSpec
  module Core
    module DSL
      def xdescribe(*args, &blk)
        describe *args do
          pending 
        end
      end

      alias xcontext xdescribe
    end
  end
end
```

Usage

```
# a_spec.rb
xdescribe "padding" do
  it "returns true" do
    1.should == 1
   end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use pending instead of describe. If your block is:

```
context "some other tests" do
  it "should do something destructive" do
    blah
  end
end
```

You can skip the whole block by:

```
pending "some other tests" do
  it "should do something destructive" do
    blah
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
describe "GET /blah" do

  before(:each) { pending "Feature to be implemented..." }

  it { expect(page).to have_button("Submit") }
  it { expect(page).to have_content("Blah") }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what's happening with your code. Including it where you have, it just gets evaluated (and hence run) when the file is loaded during startup. However you need it to be run when the tests run. That's why answers have suggested putting `pending` (RSpec 2) or `skip` (RSpec 3) into a `before` block.